# Verifying RSA signatures using .NET and powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, rsa, digital-signature

For a project I need to implement a solution to certify to many Windows machines that a file has passed through a Debian server. For this, I have to use a digital signature to make sure that the file has passed through the server.

I can't install software under windows (Goodbye GPG or PGP) so I have to use the .NET System.Security.Cryptography cryptographic library in powershell.

On Debian, I use the following command to sign my file :

```
openssl rsautl -sha256 -sign -in myfile -inkey priv.pem -out myfile.sig
```

I can't figure out how to verify my RSA signature using powershell. Do you have examples of RSA signature verification using .Net in powershell? The .NET cryptography library doesn't seem to support direct loading of PEM files, so it is necessary to convert the PEM file into a format that the RSA class would like, especially an array of bytes.

Comment: This is easily found. https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/76e487ee31539dd20aecb19fa145b2cf